# How to find selectors for elements in the Chrome Web Inspector

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I found a custom theme for my chrome web inspector but I need to make some small changes. Where do you find the selectors for the elements in the web inspector?

In the picture below I am trying to make the expand arrow white so you can see it against the background:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DevTools front end is an HTML page, so you can inspect its elements/layout via another instance of devtools. To do so, undock devtools, focus on its window and hit `Ctrl`-`Shift`-`I` (or `Cmd`-`Opt`-`I` on mac).